# feedforward network with ‘tanh’ hidden unit activation functions

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

How to show for a feedforward network with ‘tanh’ hidden unit activation functions, and a sum-of-squares error function, that the origin in weight space is a stationary point of the error function

Comment: Compute partial derivative wrt. each parameter and show it is 0.

Comment: But I am pretty sure that the bias of the output layer will not be in a stationary point, and will move towards the average target value; did you mean to also assume that mean of **y** is 0?

Comment: I think we can ignore biases